# How to create a tablespace on Windows 7 for Postgresql 9.2?

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-9.2, tablespaces

I try to run this simple command:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tb_rec
  OWNER postgres
  LOCATION 'd:/tablespaces';
```

However, the tablespace is not created and I got this message:

```
ERREUR:  n'a pas pu configurer les droits du répertoire « d:/tablespaces » : Permission denied
```

For non french speakers:

```
ERROR: was not able to configure the directory rights « d:/tablespaces » : Permission denied
```

I didn't find any postgres user (`net user`) and I'm stuck on this...

How to give access to the directory to postgres?

**Windows 7**
**Postgres 9.2**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For PostgreSQL 9.2 and above there is no `postgres` system user (by default). It runs as `NETWORK SERVICE`.

Create `d:\tablespaces` and give the `NETWORK SERVICE` (`SERVICE RÉSEAU` in french) "Full control" over it. That should do the trick.

Comment: Do you have any pointer to give "Full control"?

Comment: @Stephan Security tab of properties