# Can't create new tablespace for PostgreSQL data. Permissions denied

Tags: postgresql

For some reason I don't seem to be allowed to set my PostgreSQL data folder to a drive other than the C drive (Windows 8 machine).

1) If I try to do so when installing PostgreSQL, the installation fails. Therefore I need to choose the C drive to make installation work.

2) If I try to move the data folder later on (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Change_the_default_PGDATA_directory_on_Windows), PostgreSQL service stops running.

3) Finally, if I try to create a tablespace in the D drive, I am not allowed to do so.

When I run the following query:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE drive_D
OWNER postgres
LOCATION 'D:\PostgreSQL\data'
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "D:/PostgreSQL/data": Permission denied
SQL state: 42501
```

I am an admin on that machine and I have made sure that I have 'full control' on the D drive.

I also followed advice given on this link "[How to create a tablespace on Windows 7 for Postgresql 9.2?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83041/how-to-create-a-tablespace-on-windows-7-for-postgresql-9-2)". I gave 'NETWORK SERVICE' full control on the D drive, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason I don't seem to be allowed to change my PostgreSQL data folder to a drive other than the C drive.

This is not the correct way to do that anyway.  Creating a tablespace and moving the whole cluster are different things.

> I am an admin on that machine and I have made sure that I have 'full control' on the D drive.

It doesn't matter who **you** are, what matters is who is the service account running PostgreSQL, and what permissions that account has.

Comment: I know they are different things. That's the point, I am not allowed to do either of them. If I try to choose a data folder in the D drive when installing PostgreSQL the installation fails. If later on I try to create a tablaspace in the D drive, I am not allowed.

I don't understand the second comment.I don't know what a service account is.